# Where are you going for Mono hosting?

Tags: hosting, mono

I'm ready to deploy and I want to get my ASP.net web service off of my home development server and out onto the internet. Who would you recommend for good, reliable Mono hosting? Doesn't have to be rock-bottom cheap, just classy and stable.

Comment: If its an ASP.net web service, why are you not considering ASP.net hosting, even if you have used mono for building it?

Comment: So that the hosting environment matches my dev environment. I'm old and unaccustomed to change. The last time I secured hosting, I noticed that Windows hosting was substantially more expensive. Also, I am using ActiveRecord and SQLite and don't want my teetering technology stack to have to bear any more weight

Comment: blatant shopping question

Answer (score 3):

http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET#Hosting

Comment: Which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely get a VPS (Linode, Rimuhosting, etc) and install mono yourself. Shared hosting and mono don't make sense together for many reasons.

Comment: Well said. Today with 60/70$ per year you can get a vps running linux or unix. The money you save on MS licenses, you can get a vps

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ubiquity Hosting](http://www.ubiquityhosting.com/)

Their linux plans include Mono by default...

Answer (score 0):

Currently i am using linode and i had a pleasant experience with vpslink in the past.

Answer (score 0):

[**WebHost.UK.Net**](https://secure.webhost.uk.net/aff.php?aff=105)* tell me they support the ASP.Net Mono Framework, though I haven't used it yet. They have servers in the UK and USA.

*that's an affiliate link, I don't work for them, but I've found their Linux hosting to be very good (and very cheap)